# pylint and pep8 not work with emacs24.2?

Tags: emacs, pylint, pep8

i try to intergrate pylint and pep8 into my emacs24.2, via some code like `(require 'python-pep8)` and `(require 'python-pylint)` in my .emacs.But i got the error as shown below:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function define-compilation-mode)
   (define-compilation-mode python-pep8-mode "PEP8" (setq python-pep8-last-buffer (current-buffer)) (set (make-local-variable (quote compilation-error-regexp-alist)) python-pep8-regexp-alist) (set (make-local-variable (quote compilation-disable-input)) t))
   eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*<3>> nil "/home/zhkzyth/.emacs.d/non_forked/python-pep8.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 2399
   load-with-code-conversion("/home/zhkzyth/.emacs.d/non_forked/python-pep8.el" "/home/zhkzyth/.emacs.d/non_forked/python-pep8.el" nil nil)
 load("non_forked/python-pep8")
 eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*<2>> nil "/home/zhkzyth/.emacs.d/zhkzyth.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 1353
 load-with-code-conversion("/home/zhkzyth/.emacs.d/zhkzyth.el" "/home/zhkzyth/.emacs.d/zhkzyth.el" nil nil)
 load("zhkzyth")
 eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/zhkzyth/.emacs" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 56
 load-with-code-conversion("/home/zhkzyth/.emacs" "/home/zhkzyth/.emacs" t t)
 load("~/.emacs" t t)
 #[0 "\205\262
```

It seems like the define-compilation-mode is not defined.Any idea ?

Comment: There are a number of pylint/pep8 lisp files floating around.  The one that comes with pylint (and is available in melpa) does not have this issue.  The guy that wrote it also wrote a pep8 helper that works just as well (https://gist.github.com/ieure/302847).

Comment: @jpkotta The helper in the gist has the same complaint in the first comment.

Comment: Oops.  I guess I fixed that in my version and forgot.  The one in pylint is OK.  The gist is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like `python-pep8.el` is missing a

```
(require 'compile)
```

at the top.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry. It works!! But i still have no idea why the order is important.May i need to find some tut about emacs lisp to know more~Anyway thanks for your great help!

Comment: What order? In this case, the principle is the same as with most other languages: to use some package's functions, you need to import it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, in my case pep8 was commented out in .emacs

```
;;(require 'python-pep8)
(require 'python-pylint)
```

When I remove the comment out the problem has been fixed, seems pylint requires pep8.

```
(require 'python-pep8)
(require 'python-pylint)
```